# Powershell script copy and install certificate on remote computer

Tags: powershell, pause

Im trying to copy and install certificates on remote computers, but a i need insert a pause "press enter to continue.." at the end of each server on the loop.

```
$servers = Get-Content "D:\scripts\InstallCertRemote\servers.txt"
$LocalPath = "D:\Temp\*.*"
$RemotePath = "D$\Temp\certificates"
$logfile = "D:\scripts\InstallCertRemote\logfile.txt"

ForEach ($server in $servers)

{Get-Date | out-file $logfile -Append
Write-host Copying files on $server
(copy-item -Path $LocalPath -Destination "\\$server\$RemotePath" -Verbose 4>&1 | out-file $logfile -Append)
Start-Sleep 2
Write-host Installing certificate on $server
(Invoke-Command -ComputerName "$server" -ScriptBlock {Import-Certificate -FilePath "S:\temp\certificates\certificate.cer" -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\ROOT} -Verbose 4>&1 | out-file $logfile -Append)
}
```

How can i do it?

Thanks,

Comment: You mean like `Read-Host "press enter to continue.."; cls` ??

Comment: No, i need a pause when install a server, and press enter to continue. Just a pause with every server of the loop.

Comment: Shouldn't a simple `Read-Host` do it? Or are you looking for a `Y/N` confirmation?

Comment: yes i have tried it and i think it would work , Thanks